# Apache Zeppelin & Spark Streaming: Twitter Example won't work

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-zeppelin

I just added the example project to my Zeppelin Notebook from http://zeppelin-project.org/docs/tutorial/tutorial.html (section "Tutorial with Streaming Data"). When I run the application I get the exception:

```
<console>:67: error: value registerTempTable is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Tweet]
            rdd.registerTempTable("tweets")
```

It also **won't** work with the usage of the method

```
rdd.registerAsTable("tweets")
```

Comment: I suggest to change the title of this question, to something more related to the problem because it seems ambiguous and the solution isn't so related to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to convert your RDD to a DataFrame to apply the `registerTempTable` method.

Comment: The streaming seems to work, but I can't select any data, "%sql select * from tweets limit 10" brings no results in the table

Comment: @D.Müller I think you have a new problem and deserves a new question.